# MixPanel : mixpanel.track is logging event mulitiple times

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I am trying to track "create account event" with the help of mixpanel. 
For mixpanel Integration I have used JavaScript API.

Following is my JavaScript code :

```
function TrackAccountSuccess(email) {
     mixpanel.track("Create New Account Successful", {
         "Email": email
     });
}
```

This code is logging event more then one times even-though it is called only one time while create account.

Comment: this was happening of Mobile

Answer (score 1):

This issue is solved.

Actually in my page two times mixpanel object was initialized ( i.e. mixpanel.init(mixPanelToken) method was called. )

So I removed multiple initialization and issue is solved.